# Chat application with socket.io

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a chat application. What I'm wondering is; I have previously created my laravel project using livewire. Can I make a chat application with Socket.io? Will socket.io and livewire work successfully in the same project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.io will work with Livewire.

Those are two independent libraries.

socket.io is for bi directional communication.

Livewire is for asynchronous back end rendering.